# Is it possible to get rid of the square root in the solutions of the following symbolic quadratic equation?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, polynomials

I have a quadratic equation, which I want to solve, but don't want the square root to appear within the solutions. I tried converting the discriminant into a quadratic form but failed, not sure if this is possible. I wonder if there is any way to achieve my goal of getting rid of the discriminant in the quadratic form?

```
-4 x^2 Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a2]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 4 Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b2]^2 Sin[b3]^2 + 4 x (Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 2 Cos[a2] Cos[b2] Csc[a2 - a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[a3] Sin[b3] + Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b3]^2) == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

sol = Solve[-4 x^2 Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a2]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 
      4 Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b2]^2 Sin[b3]^2 + 
      4 x (Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 
         2 Cos[a2] Cos[b2] Csc[a2 - a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[a3] Sin[b3] + 
         Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b3]^2) == 0, x] // Simplify;
```

To eliminate the radicals, require that their argument be zero.

```
cond = Cases[sol, Sqrt[z_] :> z == 0, Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates

(* {-64 Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[a2]^2 Sin[a3]^2 Sin[b2]^2 Sin[
     b3]^2 + (4 Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 
     8 Cos[a2] Cos[b2] Csc[a2 - a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[a3] Sin[b3] + 
     4 Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b3]^2)^2 == 0} *)
```

Solving with this condition,

```
(sol2 = DeleteDuplicates[DeleteCases[
    Assuming[cond, 
     Solve[-4 x^2 Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a2]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 
         4 Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b2]^2 Sin[b3]^2 + 
         4 x (Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 
            2 Cos[a2] Cos[b2] Csc[a2 - a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[a3] Sin[b3] + 
            Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b3]^2) == 0, x] // FullSimplify],
    _?(! FreeQ[#, Undefined] &)]])
```

[image]

For the more detailed result,

```
sol3 = Assuming[cond, 
  Reduce[-4 x^2 Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a2]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 
      4 Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b2]^2 Sin[b3]^2 + 
      4 x (Csc[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[a3]^2 - 
         2 Cos[a2] Cos[b2] Csc[a2 - a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[a3] Sin[b3] + 
         Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[b3]^2) == 0, x] // FullSimplify]

(* (((Csc[a2 - a3] == 0 && Sin[a2] Sin[a3] != 0) || 
     Sin[a3] == 0) && ((x == Sin[b2]^2 && Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[b3] != 0) || 
     Csc[b2 - b3] == 0 || Sin[b3] == 0)) || (Sin[a2] == 
    0 && ((Sin[b2] == 
        0 && ((Cos[b2] Csc[a2 - a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[a3] Sin[b3] != 0 && 
           2 Cos[a2] == 
            Csc[a2 - a3] Csc[b3] Sec[b2] Sin[a3] Sin[b2 - b3] + 
             Csc[a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sec[b2] Sin[a2 - a3] Sin[b3]) || (Cos[b2] ==
             0 && Csc[b2 - b3] != 0 && 
           Sin[b3] != 
            0 && (Csc[a2 - a3] - I Csc[a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[b3] == 0 || 
             Csc[a2 - a3] + I Csc[a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[b3] == 0)) || (Csc[
             b2 - b3] == 0 && Sin[a3] Sin[b3] != 0))) || (Csc[a2 - a3] == 
        0 && (Sin[b3] == 
          0 || (Csc[b2 - b3] == 0 && 
           Sin[a3] Sin[b2] Sin[b3] != 0))))) || (Csc[a2 - a3] Sin[a2] Sin[
      a3] != 0 && 
   2 (x + Cos[b2] Cot[a2] Csc[a2] Csc[a3] Csc[b2 - b3] Sin[a2 - a3] Sin[
         b3]) == Csc[
      a2]^2 (1 + Csc[a3]^2 Csc[b2 - b3]^2 Sin[a2 - a3]^2 Sin[b3]^2)) *)
```

Comment: this result makes me puzzled, so you mean the two solutions can indeed be expressed without square roots? However, since there are two solutions, why did you get only one solution?

Comment: They can be expressed without radicals **only** under the given condition/assumption; and under that condition the two solutions are the same, I.e., become one.

Comment: I see, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I'm trying to see if this quadratic equation can be factored into two linear equations so that no square roots will be needed. Alternatively, if this is not possible, whether we can find some way to get rid of the square roots, e.g., using trig-gometries.